# How can I disallow use of a application feature based on if the device is a 3G or Non-3G device?

Tags: iphone, gps

I want to allow only users with a 3G phone to use a particular GPS function.  How do I run a check on the device before allowing that feature to be used?

Comment: Would it be better to instead let everyone try to use it, and disable it if the horiz/vert accuracy is insufficient?

Answer (score 4):

The following code with allow you to determine the exact device that is in use but I would first consider the fact that a 3G device may not actually be able to obtain a GPS lock as the process of doing so is quite slow and requires a more or less clear view of the sky.

For an iPhone 3G the result of this method will be iPhone1,2

```
- (NSString *)deviceModel
{
    NSString *deviceModel = nil;
    char buffer[32];
    size_t length = sizeof(buffer);
    if (sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &buffer, &length, NULL, 0) == 0) {
        deviceModel = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    }
    return [deviceModel autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you stop 1g phone users from using location services?  If you are near mapped WiFi you can get decent location results even without a GPS on the device.

Instead you should base your choice of what to do around the current location accuracy, if that is a reason why you seek to disable anything.